are you allowed to be wrong when discussing competitors and what already exist?
Within the specs, if you make some statements about the existing platforms or competitors in the industry where your patent application applies, are you allowed to be wrong about these statements?
Note that the term "prior art" is not used.
For example, you explicitly state that no existing platform does X, but the examiner manages to find a platform that does X?
EDITED:
What if I qualify the statement by prefixing it with "As far as the applicant is aware, ..."

Explicit comparisons are not needed and not a good idea. The examiner will do a search looking for documents that might show your invention, as claimed, is not novel or possibly obvious in light of previous work.
The primary source of cites against you will be from patent literature, not from the features of actual products. You making statements about notable products is not helpful.
It could hurt to have inaccurate statements if a court later decided you purposely redirected the examiner from looking in a fruitful area.

But will the fact of the explicit statements being wrong in it of itself have any effect on the application?

See edited answer
